# API Automation through Java or Postman

Tags: api

In my company we use Ruby to create a framework for API automation and I have heard we can automate using Postman or SoapUI. So why do we have to create a automation framework when we already have tools for it?

Answer (score -1):

It is like a buying a suit at the clothes shop versus going to a tailor to get a suit that is measured especially to your needs.

Using an existing tool will require less initial setup, you will have access to a lot of commonly needed features, without reinventing the wheel. For instance, in Postman there are available test snippets that you can use with little or no programming knowledge. Tools such as ReadyAPI, Katalon Studio, Robot Framework, SoapUI, etc. usually don't have a too steep of a learning curve, compared to developing a customer automation framework from scratch.

Using tools is fine, especially if you understand how they work in the background and have analysed the testing needs for your particular project. For example, a tool like REST Assured makes writing tests for RESTful webservices very easy, but it's actually very complex in the background.

You would build an inhouse automation framework if after researching the existing solutions, you realize they don't fully provide all that you need. A well designed/architectured framework will be far more customizable than any other tool, although it will require more initial work and maintenance as well.

In terms of using a custom test automation framework your testers will generally have to be more technical, more like SDETs rather than typical testers, but does not always has to be the case - I have seen automation frameworks build by developers and the testers would only write tests inside it by re-using the methods in the framework.

Lastly I would advise you to do some experimentation, try one of the commercial or Open Sources tools for API testing and after doing some testing with it try doing the same with a more hands-on approach, like using Python's Request client Apache Http client for Java, but every language has it's equivalent.